# Docker Compose doesn't terminate container normally, and/or hides my exit output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I seem to encounter an issue with my graceful exit code in dockerized microservice. When I run the image only with Docker, I get the desired output and data looks correct:

```
red@myhost ~/w/example> docker run example
Starting...
<Here I'm issuing termination with Ctrl+C>
^C2018-09-21 06:14:35,565 [INFO] [root] Received termination signal, initiating graceful exit.
Waiting for pending tasks to finish...
2018-09-21 06:14:35,566 [INFO] [root] Exiting
```

However, when I run this with Docker Compose - which is also used on production - I don't receive the logging output from my graceful exit code and data indeed seems to have gaps caused by terminated pending tasks:

```
red@production ~/w/example> docker-compose up example
Creating example_example_1 ... 
Creating example_example_1 ... done
Attaching to example_example_1
example_example_1    | Starting...
<Here I'm issuing termination with Ctrl+C>
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping example_example_1 ... done
```

It seems that Compose somehow hides the container output during exit, so I don't know if my code is executed or not and I can't determine futher debugging steps. I tried to find more information about this behaviour, but found only [this issue on Github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3317) that doesn't seem related, because I don't encounter issue when stopping "aborts" and leaves containers running.

Is there any way I can force Compose to show my graceful exit output, and/or any source for me to learn more about this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose run example`? Maybe `docker-compose run` is more like `docker run` than `docker-compose up`.